# Akka Http Client Pool Overflow

Tags: akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using Akka's HTTP client and I'm overflowing the connection pool. Put in pseudo code:

```
Source(myIterator).map(... make an HttpRequest)
    .via(Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[...](...))
    .runForeach { 
        case (Success(req), _) => 
            Await.ready(resp.discardEntityBytes().future(), 10 seconds)
    }
```

I've tried creating a not-default ActorMaterializer that sets all buffers to 1 and I still overflow connection pool.

I would like to not modify the pool size until I'm tuning performance.

In my reading, I suspect that the Http flow doesn't emit any backpressure 
signals because it resides in an Actor, similar to the `Sink.actorRef(...)` call?

What I would like is (1) confirmation that I'm not approaching this incorrectly and (2) how would *you*, my dear reader, mitigate this? I have a solution that uses an Actor to regulate the inflight requests using the `singleRequest()` method for the `Http()` API, but it seems overkill.

A demo example of this problem is [in a github project I made](https://github.com/basking2/akkaboom). You will have to point the HTTP URI at a big file to cause the connection to slow down enough to exhaust the default connection pool.

Thank you!

Comment: I agree with proper stream usage (and regardless of internal buffers) the pool should only overflow when you materialize the flow too often which isn't the case in your example. I created https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/955 to investigate this. Thanks for reporting!